# Flexbox Thumbnail Grid displays as 2 columns on Mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have the following HTML Page to display a Thumbnail Grid on my Website. Every column has the same heigth.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-row row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    asdfasdfasdfsdfa asdfasdf sdfasfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfsd asdf asdf Distinctio, evenietsdf
                    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.
                </p>
                <p><a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail ">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore,
                    vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel
                    blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore,
                    vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium.</p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Consequatur optio ipsa fuga vel repudiandae impedit illum delectus nihil error animi nobis
                    quaerat quidem, amet, praesentium aspernatur inventore numquam! Totam, dolorem inventore
                    reprehenderit,
                    culpa obcaecati!</p>
                <p><a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo veniam
                    tempore vero velit deleniti corporis recusandae placeat eum repellendus modi architecto, iste,
                    numquam nulla, praesentium fuga soluta eos consequatur sequi expedita! Ea aspernatur
                    explicabo optio ducimus officia blanditiis voluptas possimus veniam maxime!</p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo veniam
                    tempore vero velit deleniti corporis recusandae placeat eum repellendus modi architecto, iste,
                    numquam nulla, praesentium fuga soluta eos consequatur sequi expedita! Ea aspernatur
                    explicabo!
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /. row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

With the following style.css file.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) {
    .flex-row.row {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .flex-row.row > [class*='col-'] {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .flex-row.row:after,
    .flex-row.row:before {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
    .flex-row.row > [class*='col-'] > .box {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
    }
}
/* Grow thumbnails to fill columns height */
.flex-row .thumbnail,
.flex-row .caption {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

 /* Flex Grow Text Container */
 .flex-row .caption p.flex-text {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

If I display it in my Browser and change the View to a Smartphone size it displayes the Grid with 2 Columns. But i want that it only shows 1 Column.
Here is a screenshot how it looks right now:
[image]

How can i change my Page that it only displays 1 Column if displayed on a Smartphone/Tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `class=col-xs-6` that is why showing two columns. use `class=col-xs-12` this should solve your problem.

**working snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           </head>
<body >
  

      
<div class="container">
<div class="flex-row row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    asdfasdfasdfsdfa asdfasdf sdfasfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfsd asdf asdf Distinctio, evenietsdf
                    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.
                </p>
                <p><a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail ">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore,
                    vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel
                    blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore,
                    vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium.</p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Consequatur optio ipsa fuga vel repudiandae impedit illum delectus nihil error animi nobis
                    quaerat quidem, amet, praesentium aspernatur inventore numquam! Totam, dolorem inventore
                    reprehenderit,
                    culpa obcaecati!</p>
                <p><a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo veniam
                    tempore vero velit deleniti corporis recusandae placeat eum repellendus modi architecto, iste,
                    numquam nulla, praesentium fuga soluta eos consequatur sequi expedita! Ea aspernatur
                    explicabo optio ducimus officia blanditiis voluptas possimus veniam maxime!</p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>Title</h3>
                <p class="flex-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo veniam
                    tempore vero velit deleniti corporis recusandae placeat eum repellendus modi architecto, iste,
                    numquam nulla, praesentium fuga soluta eos consequatur sequi expedita! Ea aspernatur
                    explicabo!
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a rel="nofollow" rel="noreferrer" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- /.caption -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.thumbnail -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /. row -->
</div><!-- /.container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. Can't beleave that it was that simple. Think i must revisit the Bootstrap Grid

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to switch the column breakpoints like this..

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">..</div>
```

That way you still get 2 columns on small, and 1 columns on `xs`.

http://www.codeply.com/go/VSuGAhBCWj